# Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities [{iPhone=Safari, browserName=Safari, deviceVersion=10.3.1, platformName=iOS}]

Tags: java, ios, iphone, selenium-webdriver, appium-ios

I m trying to launch Safari Browser in Mobile using Appium on Mac.

Below are the capabilities I have used in eclipse

```
desCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.iphone();
desCapabilities.setCapability(BrowserType.IPHONE, "Safari");
desCapabilities.setCapability("browserName", "Safari");
desCapabilities.setCapability("platformName","iOS");
desCapabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone");
desCapabilities.setCapability("version", "10.3.1");
desCapabilities.setCapability("udid", "mobileID");
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://" + nodeUrl + ":" + nodeUrlPort + "/wd/hub"), desCapabilities);
```

When I try to run in eclipse, below are the exception I m facing.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities [{iPhone=Safari, browserName=Safari, platformName=iOS, udid=****, deviceName=Ananda's iPhone, version=10.3.1, platform=MAC}]
Command duration or timeout: 233 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: '*****', time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09'
System info: host: 'hostname', ip: 'ipaddress', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.4', java.version: '1.7.0_71'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
```

Kindly help me out in this.

Comment: which appium version you are using ?

Comment: And XCode version also ?

Comment: Appium Version : 1.4.13 (Draco)
Xcode Version : 8.3.2 (8E2002)

Comment: You need to use appium 1.6.4 for ios 10.3.1. Upgrade your environment and it sort the issue.Refer to link: https://github.com/appium/appium/releases/tag/v1.6.4

Answer (score 1):

To fix the issues in desired capabilities, change your code for desired capabilities as

```
desCapabilities.setCapability("browserName", "Safari");
desCapabilities.setCapability("platformName","iOS");
desCapabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "write the name of the test device (eg: myphone)");
desCapabilities.setCapability(“platformVersion”, "10.3.1");
desCapabilities.setCapability("udid", "write the mobile udid");
```

There is a difference between version and platform version.

platform Version is the mobile operating system version that you want to use in your test.
Version is the version of the browser you want to use in your test.

You can refer DesiredCapabilities [here][1].

[1]: a) https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Desired+Capabilities+Required+for+Selenium+and+Appium+Tests
b) https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities

Answer (score 0):

You need to use appium 1.6.4 for ios 10.3.1. Upgrade your environment and it will sort out the issue. Refer to below link:

github.com/appium/appium/releases/tag/v1.6.4

Appium 1.6.4 fixes numerous issues with the previous releases. This release
supports iOS 10.3 as well as Android 7.1.

And for ios 10 and onwards you have to use appium 1.6.x and ios 10.3 support has been provided in appium 1.6.4

Comment: I can able to find less than Appium 1.5.3, not 1.6.x versions.

Comment: are you searching for appium gui or appium console?

Comment: github.com/appium/appium/releases/tag/v1.6.4

Comment: this is the link you can refer to for appium 1.6.4, you have to install appium from command line.

Comment: https://discuss.appium.io/t/appium-master-ios10-xcode-8-discussion/12174

Comment: I have commented few useful links which you can refer for setting up appium 1.6.4 for ios 10.3

Comment: I m looking for Appium GUI

Comment: To interact with ios 10.3, you need to install appium 1.6.4. For appium GUI, you can use appium-deaktop which has been recently released by appium team